# Show activity only by first start up

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, startup

I have this activity, called DataActivity, and I want it to show up the first time I open my app, and never again after. Than I want my MainActivity to be my first Activity, can someone tell me how i do this? (I'm pretty new to coding so a bit of code would be appreciated...) Thanks! 
Kind regards! :)

Comment: After you call startActivity(intent) to launch your MainActivity, call finish(); on the DataActivity.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to launch activity only once when app is opened for first time?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7238532/how-to-launch-activity-only-once-when-app-is-opened-for-first-time)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code :

```
public class HelperActivity extends Activity {

    SharedPreferences prefs = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Perhaps set content view here

        prefs = getSharedPreferences("com.mycompany.myAppName", MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        if (prefs.getBoolean("firstrun", true)) {
            // Do first run stuff here then set 'firstrun' as false
            // start  DataActivity because its your app first run
            // using the following line to edit/commit prefs
            prefs.edit().putBoolean("firstrun", false).commit();
            startActivity(new Intent(HelperActivity.this , DataActivity.class));
            finish();
        }
        else {
        startActivity(new Intent(HelperActivity.this , MainActivity.class));
        finish();
        }
    }
}
```

This activity will help you decide if its first run of an application and start respective activity according to that by storing boolean value in sharedPreference

Make this activity your launcher activity.

Answer (score 0):

You could save an entry to `SharedPreferences` indicating that the `DataActivity` has been shown once, and then in `DataActivity` `onCreate()` you could do something like:

```
boolean dataShownOnce = checkSharedPreferencesForDataActivityShown();
if (dataShownOnce) {
    // Go to MainActivity
    startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    finish();
} else {
    // Showing DataActivity for the first time, continue with the normal logic
}
```

There's a pretty good tutorial on using `SharedPreferences` here: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html

Comment: thanks! had an answer that was kinda the same thing, but thanks for that tutorial! helped me a lot further as well!