# How to start the activity that is last opened when launch an application?

Tags: android, android-activity, back-stack

I designed an app with several activities. There is only an activity instance in the back stack at any time. When I quit the application from an activity named AcitivityOne, how could I launch the application with ActivityOne next time?

Comment: Have you tried activity launch modes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fast method, is that in your `onCreate()` put those `flags` after `setContentView()`:

```
if ((getIntent().getFlags() & Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT) != 0) { 
    finish(); 
    return; 
}
```

Also you can create a `SharedPreferences` with the `Activity` last oppened as follows :

Modify your `onPause()` to this :

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
  super.onPause();
  SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
  Editor editor = prefs.edit();
  editor.putString("lastopened", getClass().getName());
  editor.commit();
}
```

And then in your `onCreate()` again you put this :

```
Class<?> LastOpened;

    try {
        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
        LastOpened= Class.forName(prefs.getString("lastoppened", MainActivity.class.getName()));
    } catch(ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        LastOpened= MainActivity.class;
    }

    startActivity(new Intent(this, LastOpened));
```

If it doesn't help take a look at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7238532/how-to-launch-activity-only-once-when-app-is-opened-for-first-time)

Comment: Excellent!! Thank you very much!