# Launch login activity instead of MainActivity if app is on its first run

Tags: android, android-intent

I need my app to check if it's running for first time or not. If it's the first time, then it should launch `LoginActivity` instead of `MainActivity`. And if it's not the first run, it should display `MainActivity` as usual.

I used `SharedPreference` value to check if it's available, then app decides its not running it's first run.

This is what I've tried so far

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Set default values into settings
        PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.preferences, false);

        // Check if the app is running on its first run
        SharedPreferences fRun = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);

        if(fRun.getBoolean("firstrun", true)){

            SharedPreferences.Editor editX=fRun.edit();
            editX.putBoolean("firstrun", false);
            editX.apply();

            // Login activity stuff here
            // Goto login screen

            Intent loginIntent=new    Intent(getApplicationContext(),LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(loginIntent);

            //finish();

        } else {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is, when I run my app, it suddenly crashes and displays message `Unfortunately, the app has stopped`.

Why does the app crash? Is it because code in my `LoginActivity` have errors or do I need to first load `MainActivity` then call `LoginActivity`?

Comment: When the app is crashed u get the logs post it here it will be easier to understand where is the problem

Comment: I think that "setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); " should be anyway after "super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);". try to get it out of the if-else.

Comment: Like @MorZa mentioned, you should set your layout outside of the `if`: right now, when you exit your `LoginActivity`, you return to a blank `MainActivity`. A frequent pattern for this use-case is to start your application on a transparent `RedirectActivity`, doing nothing but redirecting the user to the wanted activity (either `MainActivity` or `LoginActivity` in your case).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to launch activity only once when app is opened for first time?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7238532/how-to-launch-activity-only-once-when-app-is-opened-for-first-time)

Comment: @YogeshRathi this is different question

Answer (score 4):

You can use LoginActivity as LAUNCHER activty and check whether the user is logged in. If yes, start MainActivity.

The AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity
    android:name=".LoginActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name">

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>

<activity android:name=".MainActivity"/>
```

And the LoginActivity:

```
public class LoginActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    private static final String LOGIN_KEY = "LOGIN_KEY";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        SharedPreferences pref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        if (pref.getBoolean(LOGIN_KEY, false)) {
            //has login
            startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
            //must finish this activity (the login activity will not be shown when click back in main activity)
            finish();
        }
        else {
            // Mark login
            pref.edit().putBoolean(LOGIN_KEY, true).apply();

            // Do something
        }
    }
}
```

The MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Do something
    }
}
```

Comment: This adds about 150-200ms overhead on the app's launch. Is there a way to avoid creating and inflating a LoginActivity if it won't be used?

Answer (score 2):

```
 <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">


        <activity android:name=".Activity.MainActivity" />

        <activity android:name=".Activity.SignupActivity" />

        <activity android:name=".Activity.SigninActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>
```

Comment: Only put your "intent-filter" into SigningActivity or LoginActivity into your AndroidMenifest.xml as like this example.

Answer (score 1):

You need to rearrange your `Activity` classes a bit I think. It's very simple to decide if your application has run first time or not and launch some `Activity` based on this decision. I would like to suggest the following architecture.

You can set a `LauncherActivity` to decide whether you need to start `LoginActivity` or `MainActivity` like this:

```
public class LauncherActivity extends Activity {

    private boolean firstLaunch = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Intent i;

        SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences(Constants.ApplicationTag, MODE_PRIVATE);
        firstLaunch = pref.getBoolean(Constants.FIRST_LAUNCH, true);

        if (firstLaunch) {
            i = new Intent(LauncherActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        } else {
            i = new Intent(LauncherActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }

        finish();
    }
}
```

You have another problem I need to sort out is calling `setContentView` inside an `else` statement which is erroneous. You need to put `setContentView` just after the `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);` in any of your `Activity`.

When you're putting it inside an `else` statement, the content view may not be set which will cause an application crash.

So remove the checking for first run from `MainActivity` and move that portion to `LauncherActivity` which will solve the problem.

The `AndroidManifest.xml` of the `LauncherActivity` may look like this

```
<activity
    android:name=".Activities.LauncherActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```